# Instance of poorly performing non tail-recursive function

Tags: algorithm, haskell, time-complexity

Below are two functions defined to find the maximum value of a list of numbers.

```
mx :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a
mx [] = error "Empty list"
mx [x] = x
mx (x:xs) 
    | x > (mx xs) = x
    | otherwise = (mx xs)

mx' (x:xs) = findMax x xs
  where
    findMax cmx [] = cmx
    findMax cmx (x:xs) | x > cmx = findMax x xs
               | otherwise = findMax cmx xs

main = do 
    print $ mx [1..30]
```

Timing the above code, first for mx' (tail-recursive) and next for mx (non-tail-recursive), we have the following timings.

```
Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y510P:/tmp$ time ./t 
30

real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.001s
Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y510P:/tmp$ ghc -O2 t.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( t.hs, t.o )
Linking t ...
Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y510P:/tmp$ time ./t 
30

real    0m6.272s
user    0m6.274s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Can someone please explain why there is such a massive difference in performance for a list of just 30 elements?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As others pointed out, GHC does not do common subexpression elimination (CSE), causing your first snippet to run in exponential time.

To see why, consider e.g.

```
test1 = length [1..1000] + sum [1..1000]
test2 = let l = [1..1000] in length l + sum l
```

The two examples are semantically equivalent, but `test1` runs in *constant space* while
`test2` in *linear space* (the whole 1000 cells get allocated). Basically, in this case CSE
negates the advantages of laziness.

Since CSE can lead to *worse* performance, GHC is quite conservative in applying it.

More explanation in GHC FAQs:

https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/FAQ#Does_GHC_do_common_subexpression_elimination.3F

Answer (score 9):

The problem is not so much the tail-recursivity, it's the fact that in `mx` in the general case you compute `mx xs` twice: once to compare it to `x`, and then a second time to return it. Each one of these calls itself calls `mx xs` twice, which then does the same, etc... resulting in an exponential run time.

You can remove this problem by simply saving the result of the first call to use it the second time:

```
mx :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a
mx [] = error "Empty list"
mx [x] = x
mx (x:xs) =
    let mxxs = mx xs in
    if x > mxxs then x else mxxs
```

Comment: Considering mx is a "pure" function (i.e. always returns the same result for the same input), it seems ghc ought to optimize the extra call to the same function away. Clearly this is not happening even with -O2.

Comment: @donatello `mx` may be a pure function, but `mx xs` will only get memoized if it's bound to a name.

Comment: @donatello: GHC generally doesn't do that sort of optimization because, in practice, it's very hard to predict when it's actually helpful and it significantly increases memory usage.

Answer (score 5):

Your second algorithm is linear, it will end up making a single pass through your list.  Your first algorithm has exponential runtime in this case (which happens to be the worst case).  You end up essentially checking everything in the list to determine that the first element, 1, is not the max.  Then you consider the second element, 2, and look at the entire rest of the list to learn that it, too, is not the max.

If you run your program using `mx` and values like `22`, `23`, ..., `30` you'll see a clearly exponential growth in runtime.

In particular, this is not merely a matter of tail-recursion vs not, this is an inefficient recursive algorithm vs an efficient one.  You could implement these in a language without tail-recursion and still see the faster performance of `mx'` over `mx`.

Comment: I think the basic problem is that (as I understand it) GHC doesn't do common subexpression elimination for recursive calls.

Comment: @dfeuer Which sounds a bit odd. Is there an open issue for that?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz CSE can also lead to worse performance, so GHC is conservative in doing that. e.g. `length [1..1000] + length [1..1000]` can be run in constant space, `let l=[1..1000] in length l + length l` allocates the whole 1000 elements. I think CSE is kind of guaranteed in ViewPatterns though, since there's no way around that.

Answer (score 3):

Calling `mx [1..3]` results in following calls:

```
mx [1..3]

    mx [2..3] -- x > (mx xs) in mx [1..3]
        mx [3] -- x > (mx xs) in mx [1..2]
        mx [3] -- otherwise = (mx xs) in mx [1..2]

    mx [2..3] -- otherwise = (mx xs) in mx [1..3]
        mx [3] -- x > (mx xs) in mx [1..2]
        mx [3] -- otherwise = (mx xs) in mx [1..2]
```

The number of `mx` calls for finding maximum of `[1..n]` is `O(2^n)`: `2^n - 1`, exactly.

`mx'` makes `O(n)` calls: `n + 1`, exactly.

```
mx' [1..3]
    findMax 1 [2, 3]
        findMax 2 [3]
             findMax 3 []
```

For `n = 30`, as in your test, `mx` makes `1073741823` calls, and `mx'` only `29`.